# Unable to get 2D array to shuffle

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I'm working on Murach's Java Programming textbook exercise 11-4, and I've got the first two methods to work properly; however my shuffle method isn't working at all. Nothing happens.

```
public static String[] suits = {"C", "S", "H", "D"};
public static int[][] cards = new int[4][13];
public static int used[] = new int[13];

public static void loadCards() {
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; j++){
            cards[i][j] = j+1;
        }
    }
}

public static void writeCards() {
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(suits[i] +" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(cards[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public static void shuffle() {

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        shuffle:
        for (int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; j++) {
            double d = Math.random() * 13;
            int random = (int) d;
            for(int test = 0; test<used.length;test++){
                if(random == used[test]) {
                    break shuffle;
                }
            }
            cards[i][j] = random;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadCards();
    writeCards();
    System.out.println("");
    shuffle();
    writeCards();
}
```

I feel like I'm starting to dig myself into a hole of wrong with the shuffle() method. Is there an easy fix I'm not seeing/am I trying something that's just absolutely wrong?

Comment: Might want to look into the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Thanks Fred! Needed to modify the algorithm slightly to take on a 2d array but problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Can't write the shuffle code for you, but you can use something like [bogo sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) to shuffle how you want. The algorithm is used both for scrambling or shuffling, and for educational purposes to show why the efficiency of sorting algorithms is so important.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, thanks to Fred Larson for pointing me in the right direction.

```
public static void shuffle() {

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        for (int j = cards[i].length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            double d = Math.random() * 13;
            int random = (int) d;
            int a = cards[i][random];
            cards[i][random] = cards[i][j];
            cards[i][j] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better take another look at that algorithm. This isn't Fisher-Yates. See the second paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors

Comment: I'll definitely try to get the Fisher-Yates algorithm down, however I'm happy with the results that the Sattolo's algorithm is producing that I coded by mistake. @FredLarson